# How do I generate a PDF from an Android app?

Tags: android, pdf

I have some values in entry boxes, checkboxes and viewboxes. I have those values to be sent on an email intent, but I also want them to be in a PDF document saved in the internal/external storage of the phone. I heard about the dynamic PDF jar library, but I really don't know how to use it.

These are my elements:

```
package com.example.kapscht;

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
CheckBox checkgrua1; 
CheckBox checkreader1; 
CheckBox checkreader2;
CheckBox checkctm1;
CheckBox checkctm2; 
CheckBox checkpsm1; 
CheckBox checkpsm2;
CheckBox checklbm1;
CheckBox checklbm2;
CheckBox checkrx1;
CheckBox checkrx2; 
CheckBox checktx1; 
CheckBox checktx2;
CheckBox checkmodulerf1;
CheckBox checkmodulerf2; 
CheckBox checkmodulemrf1;
CheckBox checkmodulemrf2;
CheckBox checkcablerf1; 
CheckBox checkcablerf2;
CheckBox checkconectorrf1;
CheckBox checkconectorrf2;
CheckBox checkatenuacionrf1;
CheckBox checkatenuacionrf2; 
CheckBox checkloopback1; 
CheckBox checkloopback2;
CheckBox checkfirmware1;
CheckBox checkfirmware2; 
CheckBox checkethernet1; 
CheckBox checkethernet2;
CheckBox checkamplificador1;
CheckBox checkamplificador2;
CheckBox checkfp1;
CheckBox checkfp2; 
CheckBox checksincro1; 
CheckBox checksincro2;
CheckBox checkotro1;
CheckBox checkotro2;
EditText etcliente;
EditText etsitio; 
EditText etrampa;
EditText etfalla;
EditText etdescripcion;
EditText etqg;
EditText etprevio;
EditText etdejarsitio;
TextView vwfecha1; 
TextView vwfecha2; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Date date = new Date();
    String dateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);
    vwfecha1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vwfecha1);
    vwfecha1.setText(dateTime);
    checkgrua1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkgrua1);
    checkreader1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkreader1);
    checkreader2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkreader2);
    checkctm1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkctm1);
    checkctm2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkctm2);
    checkpsm1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkpsm1);
    checkpsm2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkpsm2);
    checklbm1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checklbm1);
    checklbm2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checklbm2);
    checkrx1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkrx1);
    checkrx2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkrx2);
    checktx1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checktx1);
    checktx2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checktx2);
    checkmodulerf1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkmodulerf1);
    checkmodulerf2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkmodulerf2);
    checkmodulemrf1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkmodulemrf1);
    checkmodulemrf2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkmodulemrf2);
    checkcablerf1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkcablerf1);
    checkcablerf2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkcablerf2);
    checkconectorrf1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkconectorrf1);
    checkconectorrf2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkconectorrf2);
    checkatenuacionrf1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkatenuacionrf1);
    checkatenuacionrf2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkatenuacionrf2);
    checkloopback1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkloopback1);
    checkloopback2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkloopback2);
    checkfirmware1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkfirmware1);
    checkfirmware2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkfirmware2);
    checkethernet1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkethernet1);
    checkethernet2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkethernet2);
    checkamplificador1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkamplificador1);
    checkamplificador2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkamplificador2);
    checkfp1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkfp1);
    checkfp2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkfp2);
    checksincro1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checksincro1);
    checksincro2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checksincro2);
    checkotro1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkotro1);
    checkotro2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkotro2);
    etcliente= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcliente);
    etrampa= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etrampa);
    etprevio= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etprevio);
    etdejarsitio= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdejarsitio);
    etsitio= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etsitio);
    etfalla= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etfalla); 
    etdescripcion= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdescripcion);
    etqg= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etqg);
    View boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);
    boton.setOnClickListener(this); 

}
```

And this is the email intent action:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==findViewById(R.id.enviar).getId())
    {

        Intent intentEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "villasantdesign@gmail.com", null));
        intentEmail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"villasantdesign@gmail.com"});
        intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Consulta Técnica");
        intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Fecha/hora abierto: "
        +vwfecha1.getText().toString()
        +"\n"
        +"\nFecha/hora cerrado: "
        +vwfecha2.getText().toString()
        +"\n"
        +"\nCliente:  "+etcliente.getText()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSitio:  "+etsitio.getText()
        +"\n"
        +"\nRampa:  "+etrampa.getText()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe usó grua:  "+checkgrua1.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nEstado del equipo  "
        +"\nPrevio a la visita:  "+etprevio.getText()
        +"\nAl dejar el sitio:  "+etdejarsitio.getText()
        +"\n"
        +"\nFalla Reportada:  "+etfalla.getText()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó reader/lector: "+checkreader1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó reader/lector: "+checkreader2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó CTM:  "+checkctm1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó CTM:  "+checkctm2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó PSM: "+checkpsm1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó PSM: "+checkpsm2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó LBM:  "+checklbm1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó LBM:  "+checklbm2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó Antena Rx: "+checkrx1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó Antena Rx: "+checkrx2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó Antena Tx:  "+checktx1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó Antena Tx:  "+checktx2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó Módulo RF: "+checkmodulerf1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó Módulo RF: "+checkmodulerf2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó Módulo MRF:  "+checkmodulemrf1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó Módulo MRF:  "+checkmodulemrf2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó Cable/Jumper RF: "+checkcablerf1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó Cable/Jumper RF: "+checkcablerf2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó Conector RF:  "+checkconectorrf1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó Conector RF:  "+checkconectorrf2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó Atenuación RF: "+checkatenuacionrf1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó Atenuación RF: "+checkatenuacionrf2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó Cable Loopback RF: "+checkloopback1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó Cable Loopback RF: "+checkloopback2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó SW/Firmware: "+checkfirmware1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó SW/Firmware: "+checkfirmware2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó Conexión Ethernet:  "+checkethernet1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó Conexión Ethernet:  "+checkethernet2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó Amplificador: "+checkamplificador1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó Amplificador: "+checkamplificador2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó FP Amp.:  "+checkfp1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó FP Amp.:  "+checkfp2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó Sincronización: "+checksincro1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó Sincronización: "+checksincro2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nSe reemplazó OTRO:  "+checkotro1.isChecked()
        +"\nSe ajustó OTRO:  "+checkotro2.isChecked()
        +"\n"
        +"\nDescripción de reparación: "+etdescripcion.getText()
        +"\n"
        +"\nQuien genera: "+etqg.getText());            
        intentEmail.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentEmail, "Enviar"));         
        }}}
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far?  I see that you're collecting data and sending an email but I don't see where you have tried to use the PDF library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are Some examples of how you can do that:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPDF/article.html
http://karanbalkar.com/2013/05/tutorial-22-generate-pdf-using-droidtext-in-android/
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/image.html